# s3.upload() works but uploads broken image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I've got a Lambda function in AWS that is hooked up to a POST method which basically takes an image URL and uploads the image to an S3 bucket.

My Lambda function looks like this:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  let encodedImage = JSON.parse(event.body).user_avatar;
  let decodedImage = Buffer.from(encodedImage, 'base64');
  var filePath = "avatars/" + event.queryStringParameters.username + ".jpg"

  var params = {
    "Body": decodedImage,
    "Bucket": "MYBUCKETNAME.com",
    "Key": filePath
  };
  s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err, null);
    } else {
      let response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
          "my_header": "my_value"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify(data),
        "isBase64Encoded": false
      };
      callback(null, response);
    }
  });
};
```

It seems to upload the image to the bucket specified, but when I view the image it seems to be broken.

[image]

I'm very inexperienced with using AWS for anything outside of the GUI they provide. If anyone has any idea of what might be going on I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just tested your lambda function code through API Gateway, it works fine and there is no image corruption after it was uploaded to S3. Only possible issue will be with your base64 string input is not correct.

Comment: This seemed to be the issue, I was passing in an image URL when in fact I should have been passing in a base 64 string

Comment: ohh. glad its resolved!!!

Answer (score 1):

When uploading an image file you should also specify the content type. For jpeg it is `image/jpeg`. For png it is `image/png`. If you leave out content type the image might not display at all (just black space).

[Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

There are node.js libraries to figure out the image type for you. This is just one of many such libraries:

[image-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-type)

```
var params = {
  Body: decodedImage,
  Bucket: "MYBUCKETNAME.com",
  Key: filePath,
  Content-Type: 'image/jpeg'
};
```

Comment: I think `Content-Type` is a typo. I tried it with `ContentType: 'image/jpeg'` and I still see a broken transparent image

Comment: Download the file and then view with a picture viewer. This will verify if the file is actually valid or corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

For those still dealing with a similar problem. Consider also, if you read the file after the upload, then send the same file without resetting the cursor to 0, you will damage the file since S3 will start reading from where the cursor was left. In my case, I was reading it to find out the content of the image.

So if you reset the cursor before calling `upload_fileobj` it will fix it:

```
    try:
        file.seek(0) //resets the cursor.
        s3_client.upload_fileobj(
            file,
            bucket_name,
```