# Not able to connect to AWS documentDb from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to connect to AWS documentDB from Lambda function but, not able to connect.

`MongoClient.connect` never calls the callback function connected.

`TLS is off` on documentDB Cluster.  I'm able to connect via mongo shell.

Lambda & documentDB are in `same VPC & Security group`.

```
'use strict';

module.exports.search = async (event, context, callback) => {

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://xxx:xxxx@xxx-db.cluster-xxx.us-east-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017";

console.log("Starting");

MongoClient.connect(url, 
    { 
        useNewUrlParser: true
    },
    function(err, client) {
        if(err)
            throw err;

        console.log("Connected");

        db = client.db('mydb');

        col = db.collection('mycollection');

        col.find({}).toArray().then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            return { statusCode: 200, body: result };
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('=> an error occurred: ', err);
            return { statusCode: 500, body: 'error' };
        });

    });

};
```

Output only prints `starting` which was consoled before calling `Mongo.Connect`.
How to identify or debug the issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Just from looking at the current code I am pretty sure your function exit before it is able to complete. Therefore, your callback is not executed

Because MongoClient.connect runs asynchronously

Try to take a look at some resource around async/await/promise and Lambda

https://medium.com/tensult/async-await-on-aws-lambda-function-for-nodejs-2783febbccd9

[How to wait for async actions inside AWS Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633912/how-to-wait-for-async-actions-inside-aws-lambda/41833459)

Comment: yes, when i added await, the request keeps getting timeout. Seems like not able to get the documentDb connection. Is their any way we can get the trace of error ?

Comment: Now this would suffice to go through another question or else it will get complicated here
For me the best thing you could do to trace is that : 

1/ Create a public mongoDB on the internet
2/ Connect to that DB through your Lambda ( Make sure you have a nat instance to give your lambda inside VPC internet access )
3/ Then you can make sure your code running normally.
4/ After that, look back at the connectivity between Lambda and DocumentDB

Comment: Solved ! seems like there is some issue with AWS documentDB connection. Even if `TLS is disabled` on cluster, you still need to provide `sslCA` to connect which is strange.

Comment: @AtulSharma, this is not expected. When you disabled TLS, did you reboot the instanced in your cluster? If you change the parameter to disable TLS, it only takes hold after a reboot. For more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/security.encryption.ssl.html