# Invoking AWS Lambda from Another lambda, child lambda stop immediately

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Yes I have seen many post and stackoverflow answer on how to invoke a lambda from another lambda asynchronously. I'm able to call child lambda from parent lambda. but don't know why my child lambda function closes immediately within 100ms look like my child lambda is working synchronously with my parent lambda.

this is my parent lambda having HttpAPI type gateway:

```
// PARENT LAMBDA having HttpAPI gateway.

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const auth = require("./services/auth");
var Lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

/**
* Note: Step Functions, which are called out in many answers online, do NOT actually work in this case. The reason
* being that if you use Sequential or even Parallel steps they both require everything to complete before a response
* is sent. That means that this one will execute quickly but Step Functions will still wait on the other one to
* complete, thus defeating the purpose.
*
* @param {Object} event The Event from Lambda
*/
// LAMBDA A
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
user = auth.authenticateUser(event);
const userId = auth.authenticateUser(event);
if (!user) {
return auth.UNAUTHORISED;
}
let params = {
FunctionName: "my-child-lambda-here",
InvocationType: "Event", // <--- This is KEY as it tells Lambda to start execution but immediately return / not wait.
Payload: JSON.stringify(event),
};

// we have to wait for it to at least be submitted. Otherwise Lambda runs too fast and will return before
// the Lambda can be submitted to the backend queue for execution
// LAMBDA B
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
Lambda.invoke(params, function (err, data) {
if (err) {
reject(err, err.stack);
} else {
console.log(data);
resolve("Lambda invoked: " + data);
}
});
});
// Always return 200 not matter what
return {
statusCode: 200,
body: "Your request is currently being processed",
};
};
```

this is my child lambda:

```
// CHILD LAMBDA!!
exports.handler = async (event) => {
console.log("inside child Lambda!!!!!!!!!!!")
console.log(event)
let i = 0;
// repeat with the interval of 1 seconds
let timerId = setInterval(() => console.log("count: ", i++), 1000);
console.log("inside child Lambda print 2!!!!!!!!!!!")
setTimeout(() => console.log("setTimoutTesting"), 10);

// after 15 seconds stop
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(timerId); console.log("stop"); }, 15000);

// TODO implement
const response = {
statusCode: 200,
body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
};
return response;
};
```

my yaml have following iam set to allow another lambda invocation:

```
provider:
name: aws
memorySize: 128
runtime: nodejs14.x
lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
region: us-east-2
iam:
role:
name: invoke-other-lambda-role
statements:
- Effect: 'Allow'
# Resource: '*'
Resource: 'arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:*'
Action:
- 'lambda:InvokeAsync'
- 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
```

Comment: Why would you expect your child lambda to wait longer? Because of the timeout stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on node.js but as far as I know the lambda handler doesn't actually wait until `setTimeout()`  has finished.  If you want to really wait for the timeout to occur you should convert it to a `Promise` object and `await` on it in the same function.  A good example on that can be found here (the code snippet should be self-explanatory): https://stackoverflow.com/a/42183439/12259756.

My question would be though why you would do this in the first place because lambda is in incredibly expensive service for this use-case of waiting for 15 seconds compared to other technologies.  A cheap way to include waits in your logic would be for example a Step Function.